# Python catch exceptions from secondary module

Tags: python, exception

I have a module which imports `psycopg2`. Call this module `A`

I have a second module, `B` which imports module `A`.

If `psycopg2` throws a custom exception (which is not handled by `A`), such as `psycopg2.OperationalError`,

How can I handle the exception in module `B` without having to import `psycopg2`?

Do I need to create some kind of proxy in module `A` to basically rethrow `psycopg2.OperationalError` as `A.OperationalError`?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, rethrowing the exception as a different class defined in module A is a very good way to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

You can create another exception type in A/B or catch all exceptions (which is not really good).